# regex match replace multiple times (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to normalize a file removing part of the text.
An sample string extracted from the file is the following:

```
"a":{"$":"word"}, "b":{"$":"100"}, "c": {"$":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00"}
```

The target should be:

```
"a":"word","b":"100","c":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00"
```

I identified a regular expression that matches my requirement:

```
var regex = /{"\$":(.*)"}/g;
```

But when I do the replacement (found similar code in stackoverflow):

```
let targetString = sourceString.replace(regex, "$1");
```

I have to problems, only the first match is replaced and a "}" is not handled properly.

```
"a":"word"},"b":{"$":"100"},"c":{"$":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00
```

Below the full code and the console log:

```
let jsonC1 = `"a":{"$":"word"}, "b":{"$":"100"}, "c":{"$":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00"}`;
//matches (regex) all white spaces and replace them with no space
let jsonN = jsonC1.replace(/\s/g,'');
console.log(`jsonN: ${jsonN}`);
var regex = /{"\$":(.*)"}/g;
let jsonS = jsonN.replace(regex, "$1");
console.log(`jsonS: ${jsonS}`);
```

jsonN: "a":{"$":"word"},"b":{"$":"100"},"c":{"$":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00"}

jsonS: "a":"word"**}**,"b":**{"$":"100"}**,"c":**{"$":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00**

Cheers, Giovanni

Comment: Replace `.*` by `.*?`.

Comment: `...replace(/\{"\$":|\}/g,'')` should do the job.

Comment: Either `/\s*\{"\$":("[^"]*")\}/g`  or `/\s*\{"\$":(".*?")\}/g` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks everybody.

Comment: Thanks everybody.
- Xufox: your code result: jsonS: "a":"word,"b":"100,"c":"2017-02-08T16:20:36+13:00
- LukStorm: second one does the trick, " in the parenthesis is the magic, not sure why ? is required, though
- @RobG: your code works just fine but... the replacing '' left me puzzled! Don't understand how it works.

Comment: That ? changes the .* to lazy matching. The default is greedy matching.  For example. `X.*X` would match the whole string 'XyyXzzX', while `X.*?X` is lazy and would only match 'XyyX' in that string.

Comment: @LukStorms thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
const targetString = data.replace(/\s*{".*?"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"}\s*/g, `"$1"`)
```

`\s*` is used to remove all extra spacing.